# Remove footer message sent by Google Form Notifications

Tags: google-forms

I have a google form that sends email to recipient upon completion of the form. However, I notice that there is a footer set by Google that says "This is an automated message was sent to you by the --> Form Notifications add-on for Google Forms.". Is it possible to turn this off?

Here is the add-on:
https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/form_notifications/573009629797?hl=en&pann=forms_addon_widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot turn it off. It is there by design.

In any case, your best bet for questions about various add-ons is their respective forums.
For Form Notifications please go to: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs